# Angular Nested Scope Not Responding to Broadcast After Local Modification

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**EDIT>** Here's a better Plunk of what I'm trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/E5WU0IJ5eZOJmr393AFU?p=preview

Kept for legacy -> Here's OLD Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/7q2qJq8LEPtNwcl8RZqE?p=preview

I have 2 buttons that do open/close by  sending out a `$broadcast` to its children.

The child controllers listen for the `$on` open/close click and modify the boolean `open` accordingly.

However, if I modfy the `open` boolean from within the local scope, the `$on` listener seems to become detached and no longer fires.

I would suggest looking at the plunker but here's the source:

script.js:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('BaseCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.items = ['foo', 'bar', 'tar', 'far', 'car'];
    }
  ])
  .controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.open = true;

      $scope.$on('Open_True', function() {
        $scope.open = true;
      });
      $scope.$on('Open_False', function() {
        $scope.open = false;
      });

    }
  ]);
```

And the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="BaseCtrl">

  <button ng-click="$broadcast('Open_True')">Open All</button>
  <button ng-click="$broadcast('Open_False')">Close All</button>

  <br><br>

  <div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat-start="item in items">
      Item: {{item}}
      <br>We are open: {{open}}
      <!-- This is the button that breaks it all -->
      <button ng-click="open=!open">Toggle Open</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end style="padding-left: 1em">
      Item: {{item}}
      <br>We are open: {{open}}
      <hr style="margin-left:-1em;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think the problem is where my `ItemCtrl` is, but not really sure. My biggest problem is I need to do the `ng-repeat-start` because I have two sibling elements that need to repeat so I can't place the controller in the first `div` block.

thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that when you use `ng-repeat` a child scope is created. When you change `open` on one of the children, it uses its own locally scoped `open` variable, and no longer respects the parent scope's version of `open`.

You can use `$parent.open` to explicitly change or access the parent scope's version of `open` from within the child scope.

Here's an updated [**PLUNK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zDSUNWLNq5JXPsWL6sWr?p=preview) that shows the status of the `open` variable in both the parent and local scope for each item so you can see what's really happening when you broadcast to the parent scope.

**--EDIT--**

You can solve this by adding a controller for the child elements. Then in the controller, you can listen for the broadcast and update accordingly:

In your markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
```

In your script:

```
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('Open_True', function(){
    $scope.open = true;
  });
  $scope.$on('Open_False', function(){
    $scope.open = false;
  });
}])
```

updated [**PLUNK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bil2gkhrv8lgoVcM1S7s?p=preview) that shows that the child scope now respects the broadcast.

**--EDIT--**

If you just want sibling elements that repeat, instead of using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` you can just repeat one div with two nested siblings:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
  Item: {{item}}
  <button ng-click="open=!open" >Toggle Open</button>
  <!-- SIBLINGS -->
  <div>Sibling one is open: {{open}}</div>
  <div style="margin-left: 1em;">Sibling two is open: {{open}}</div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Another updated [**PLUNK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xhtq3ECKItrRpLDkGoCP?p=preview)

**--EDIT--**

Since you mentioned that the desired output is a table, with a row being repeated.. That can be done in the same way:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <td><button ng-click="open=!open">toggle</button></td>
    <!-- SIBLINGS -->
    <td>Sibling 1 is open: {{open}}</td>
    <td>Sibling 2 is open: {{open}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

hopefully the final updated [**PLUNK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xhtq3ECKItrRpLDkGoCP?p=preview).

Comment: This makes sense and as I was driving home I realized this is what was happening. I understand your changes, but the difference, and the challenge of why I posted this question, is getting the two sibling elements (in my original plunk) to share the same value of 'open' whilst allowing $broadcast listening. From this point, I think the only way to do it, is to use a service and bind each <div> up by the $index value from ng-repeat. Not sure.
-- EDIT --  
In my actual problem, not example, I'm using <tr>'s so I can't use your ng-repeat example posted 3rdly.

Comment: @Skinner927 I finally understand the real issue, see my most recent edit above.

Comment: Maybe this illustrates what I'm trying to do a little better and why I'm unable to put the siblings in a wrapper :( http://plnkr.co/edit/E5WU0IJ5eZOJmr393AFU?p=preview

Comment: I think I got it working. You obviously know Angular better than me, is this a valid way to do this? http://plnkr.co/edit/Vd8QmOcjFHYxVno1LHOl?p=preview

Comment: That works, it's a little messy though. I'd still try to wrap them and just use `ng-repeat`. You can wrap row groups in `tbody` elements, there can be many of them per table, it's a good generic element to use as a wrapper. Then you won't need to worry about the $index part when broadcasting. Here's the updated [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/MmhIwuQ5X3fILx6V97eC?p=preview). Does that seem like a good solution?

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't realize you could have multiple `tbody`s. Thanks for the help, it's perfect!